# Прочитать данные из json файла React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не получается прочитать данные из `json` файла и вывести в консоль.

Что я делаю не так?

[Ссылка на Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-dream-dlltt?file=/App.js)

```
import React from "react";

    class App extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://stepan-ivanov93.myjino.ru/test/anothercust.json")
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            console.log("data:", data);
          });
      }
    
      render() {
        return <div>Test</div>;
      }
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: А что ваш сервер back end может ответить на такой запрос "http://stepan-aivanov93.myjino.ru/test/anothercust.json" ? если нет то постарайтесь это сделать

Comment: Там просто лежит json файл. Не получится его просто прочитать и вывести?

Comment: Это запрос к серверу. Если его никто не обработает то вернется 404

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего Ваша проблема на стороне сервера, все работает если воспользоваться тестовым сервисом [JSON placeholder:](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com)

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log("data:", data)
      })
  }
  
  render() {
    return <h1>Test title</h1>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
)
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```